# Having an issue with Regex on iOS - Related to Expression Flags?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm having real trouble working out why my Regular Expression works in http://regexr.com/ but not in my Objective C project - I'm fairly new to Regex, so it may be something quite basic!

The Regex I'm using is:

```
/[A-Z0-9\._%+-]+(\s*@\s*|\[\[*at\]\]|\s*\[*\{*\(*\s*]*at\s*\]*\}*\)*\s*)[A-Z0-9\.-:]+(\s*\.\s*|\s*\[*\{*\(*\s*(dot|\.)\s*\]*\}*\)*\s*)[a-z]*(\s*\.\s*|\/|\s*\[*\{*\(*\s*dot\s*\]*\}*\)*\s*)?[a-z]*/igm
```

Which is available to view here - http://regexr.com/3c8up

I've added to my Xcode Project both with, and without the preceding and following '/' and 'igm' Expression flags - and I have the same result. No Matches.

Here is my code.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"/[A-Z0-9\\._%+-]+(\\s*@\\s*|\\[\\[*at\\]\\]|\\s*\\[*\\{*\\(*\\s*]*at\\s*\\]*\\}*\\)*\\s*)[A-Z0-9\\.-:]+(\\s*\\.\\s*|\\s*\\[*\\{*\\(*\\s*(dot|\\.)\\s*\\]*\\}*\\)*\\s*)[a-z]*(\\s*\\.\\s*|\\/|\\s*\\[*\\{*\\(*\\s*dot\\s*\\]*\\}*\\)*\\s*)?[a-z]*/igm";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *tweetOriginalText = aTweet.text;
NSMutableAttributedString * tweetAttributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tweetOriginalText];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:tweetOriginalText options:NSMatchingProgress range:NSRangeFromString(tweetOriginalText)];
NSLog(@"MATCHES: %i", [matches count]);
```

Here is my log - you can see that there should be some matches!

```
2015-11-23 13:51:43.477 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] @maven46 hey we have multiple travel clients including one global brand. dm me or ross[at]http://t.co/3pnlwlwmvo if you want to chat :-)
2015-11-23 13:51:43.477 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] --------------------------
2015-11-23 13:51:43.478 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] @rachelmsavage we'd be more than happy to put you in touch with one of our freelance developers. dm me or ross[at]http://t.co/3pnlwlwmvo
2015-11-23 13:51:43.478 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] --------------------------
2015-11-23 13:51:43.479 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] @cgcorcoran hey caroline- we are one of those companies. dm or ping me an email ross(at)http://t.co/3pnlwlwmvo if you need pics/quotes
2015-11-23 13:51:43.479 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] --------------------------
2015-11-23 13:51:43.545 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] MATCHES: 0
2015-11-23 13:51:43.549 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] MATCHES: 0
2015-11-23 13:51:43.552 Unobfuscater[6577:3235202] MATCHES: 0
```

I'd really appreciate any assistance with figuring this out... I'm so close :-)

Comment: I guess there is an issue with you code. I get all matches with [this code](https://ideone.com/dU2GhO)

Comment: Thanks - I'll give yours a look through. The difference seems to be around my 'options' if nothing else is vastly different. 

Fortunately I managed to find a Library of RegEx Categories - which has resolved the issue! https://github.com/bendytree/Objective-C-RegEx-Categories

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to stribizhev's snippet - it looks like my issue is around my pattern including preceding and following '/' as well as the flags from the regular expression tool I used - I did try the (?i) flag also previously - but it looks to be the pattern as well as the options I have included when working with my NSRegularExpression - a few too many mistakes!

For the record - I resolved it by using these Categories - https://github.com/bendytree/Objective-C-RegEx-Categories but thanks **stribizhev**!